# Changing set of jars for Spring MVC application resulted in java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have working Spring WEB MVC application.   I need to add Hibernate persistence layer, so I downloaded Spring Pet Clinic application from Github:
http://spring.io/blog/2013/03/21/spring-petclinic-is-on-github

Only changing jars to the set of jars from the Petclinic application (Spring version 4.0.1) results in the following error

```
12:38:54.039 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory -   Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'viewResolver'
12:38:54.039 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'viewResolver'
12:38:54.061 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.needsRefresh(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InjectionMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:383) ~[spring-orm-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:332) ~[spring-orm-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:844) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems there is a conflict of Spring modules' versions.

> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:332) **~[spring-orm-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]**
>
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:844) **~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]**

Make sure all your Spring dependencies have the same version.

Comment: Yes, somehow this jar remained at org.eclipse.wst.common.component